# Options for user-defined CMake functions

Tags: cmake

```
function(print2Args arg1 arg2)
  message(STATUS ${arg1} " " ${arg2})
endfunction(print2Args)
```

Is it possible to update user defined function `print2Args` s.t. it will accept *options* like the built-in CMake function [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake offers this via the `CMakeParseArguments`. You do not specify the arguments in the function signature as you did in your example.

CMake accepts more arguments then given in the function signature. You define options, one-valued arguments and pairs of arguments in variables and pass these to `cmake_parse_arguments`. This command sets several variables which you can use to check what arguments where set.

Documentation and an example:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeParseArguments.html